# combining the results of two select statements mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I look at all the other examples and none of them correspond to my results.

I have:

```
select last_name, first_name from customer;
select address, district, phone from address;
```

I can't use union due to the different number of columns.  I have tried join, but I'm not sure if I'm using it properly.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Post some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: you need a foreign key or a common field in both tables that allows to join both records

Comment: If you just want it to put the results in the same grid for 1 row, select an empty string in your first statement (`SELECT last_name, first_name, '' as 'col' FROM customer UNION ALL select address, district, phone FROM address;`) and then you can `UNION` as long as the columns are the same data types.  you might have to `CAST` phone to be nvarchar if it's stored differently.  If you actually want the name and address of the same person, you'll have to `JOIN` your tables on a key field (like a CustomerID field).

Comment: That worked thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from both tables you need to have some sort of foreign key in address table. Then your query would look like this:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, address, district, phone FROM customer c
INNER JOIN address a ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id
```

Customer_id is primary key of customer table.